Mailchimp Tls1.2 Issue
Mailchimp's documentation suggests that it supports Tls1.2. See here: https://mailchimp.com/developer/release-notes/retiring-legacy-versions-of-transport-layer-security-tls-protocol/
I have been testing basic curl calls from multiple locations and Mailchimp always returns a Handshake failure (I checked with Wireshark). I have triple-checked that I have the right certificates installed.
If I run a curl and force Tls1.3, it works. I'd love to see if anyone can successfully connect to the Mailchimp API with Tls1.2. We're running on a legacy server and connecting with Tls1.3 is not an easy feat - it's running in the .NET framework.
If there's people out there still using Tls1.2 I'll eat my words, but honestly this looks like an undocumented update. Their support doesn't know anything about it either, and they're not very helpful.
